# Object height and position change on window when scrolling document

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, offset

How to do with jquery and/or CSS ? :

I have a fixed object which is let's say at original-top : '0' (from document top) and original-height : '10px'.
I would like that when scrolling down the document, the object changes its top position to down and it grows its height. So when we arrive at the bottom of the document, the object stops at the bottom of the window (and bottom of the document) and finishes at 100px of height.
And back way, when we scroll upto the document top, it finishes at 'top : 0' and 'height : 10px'.

Comment: you likely got the negative vote because it looks like you haven't tried anything at all. You haven't posted any code at all. If you put up a jsfiddle and it looks like you've tried and are making it easier for us to help you, then you're more likely to get help.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Dave Briand... of course i tried, who knows that i did not ? He/she should just ask like you... but as i am not an expert in jquery, my trials are zero.
So, for example :
  `$(function(){
   $(document).scroll(function() {
    var $myDiv = $('#copyright');
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    $myDiv.height( st );
    if( st == 0 ) {
     $myDiv.css('top',0);
    } else {
     $myDiv.css('top','auto');
    }
   }).scroll();
  })` and i have other kind of scripts also, would you like i show the others ? :)

Comment: think if your problem as a math problem:

startingHeight = 10px;
finalHeight = 100px;

The rate of growth from startingHeight to finalHeight is your currentScrollPosition (which you can get with jquery scrollTop()) divided by the pageHeight (which you can get with jquery.height() being called on a page wrapper. Put these calcs in a scroll event handler.

scrollPercentage = currentScrollPosition / pageHeight;

scrollPercentage shows you how far down the page you've gone, which means how much of the height of your fixed box.

fixedBoxHeight = finalHeight * scrollPercentage.

Comment: @Dave Briand - thanks a lot... but i think i will not be able to do it by myself, i will try it and i come back if i will succeed :)

Comment: here's a fiddle to get you started - http://jsfiddle.net/nuB2j/

Comment: @Dave Briand ah, yesss, this is what i want !!! i integrate to my test and come back to tell you if it works...

Comment: @Dave Briand - so, it works, the only thing is that the object does not finish at the bottom of the window. It should stay on the screen until i scoll upto the document bottom... 
I changed the "wrapper" to "document" : `var finalTop = $(document).height();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2D4U/10/

this code is in the fiddle - i've left in the console commands so you can watch progress as you scroll:

```
var initialTop = 300;
var initialHeight = 10;
var finalHeight = 500;
var heightOffset = $(window).height();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();// - heightOffset;
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
console.log('Window Height: ' + windowHeight);
console.log('Document Height: ' + documentHeight);

$('#box').height(initialHeight).css('top',initialTop);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPercentage = $(window).scrollTop() / (documentHeight - windowHeight);
    console.log('SP: ' + scrollPercentage);
    var newHeight = scrollPercentage * (finalHeight);
    $('#box').height(newHeight);
    var newTop = scrollPercentage * (windowHeight - newHeight - initialTop);
    $('#box').css('top', newTop + initialTop);
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! However, it does not stop at the window bottom when it reaches the document bottom. I made a fiddle with the same codes but i increased wrapper height upto 5900 px. you will see, the box disappears from the window... : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/Y2D4U/4/ I would like that the box stops at the bottom of window when the document (website) ends at the end.

Comment: check it now - you might find some interesting behaviour if your box height is a significant percentage of your window height

Comment: Yesss, this is what i wanted ! You see, not only that you understood but you gave me an acceptable answer as well ! And there are people with hate and bad wishes to click immediately to vote down free but do not even ask or answer... :)
Just please edit and update your answer codes to the new one... thanks again !

Comment: aie, just another thing... when i put initialTop=300, it puts the box at 300px from top but when i start to scroll, it jumps back to 0px top and starts the scroll from there... do you know why ? Is it complicated if i want to change the start point ? : http://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/Y2D4U/15/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2D4U/16/ solves that - think about the problem you're seeing in terms of math. You need to add the offset of the initial top because it was getting re-written in the scroll handler.

Comment: Wauh ! Excellent ! In fact, not the mathematic part which cause a problem but mainly the coding... i should know the expressions, values, etc. Thanks a lot, i gave you a lot of job for today, you worked well :)))

Comment: LOL Just a moment... now it does not stop at the document end but (i guess) object height's pixel downer...

Comment: I got it alone !!! :))) i corrected it : `var newTop = scrollPercentage * (windowHeight - newHeight - finalHeight);`  so, not math but the expressions... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56438/discussion-between-dave-briand-and-igor-laszlo).